# Hibernate generates wrong foreign key constraint for OneToOne association?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

We have the following column definition in Table T1 which has columns, A, B and C and should reference Table T2 with columns A, B and D, where A and B are part of primary key and D is not. Column C does not exist in Table T1. We need to map Column C on Column D.

```
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "A", referencedColumnName = "A")
  @JoinColumn(name = "B", referencedColumnName = "B")
  @JoinColumn(name = "C", referencedColumnName = "D")
  private T2 t2;
```

And Hibernate generates the following alter table statement:

```
alter table T1 
   add constraint FKqrwipa0yxatqw2rsgpdm93wle 
   foreign key (A, B, C) 
   references T2
```

From our current understanding the alter table constraint is wrong.
Should not it contain the referencedColumnNames? Our expectation (and need) is

```
alter table T1 
   add constraint FKqrwipa0yxatqw2rsgpdm93wle 
   foreign key (A, B, D) 
   references T2
```

Because Column "C" does not exist in Table T2, only "D" exists there.
So all statements against this model will fail.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

That's just how this annotation is defined. The join column as defined by `name` is the one on the table of the declaring entity. The `referencedColumnName` is the one on the table of the target entity. If the columns on the source table `T1` are `A`, `B`, `D` and on the target `T2` are `A`, `B`, `C`, then you need to swap the column names.

Comment: T1 has the columns A, B and C and T2 has the columns A, B, D. Clarified the question, too.

Comment: Like I wrote, this is how it is defined. If you want it the other way, swap the column names.